# Using synchronized keyword while using DateFormat in a multithreading environment

Tags: java, multithreading, simpledateformat, indexoutofboundsexception

Where to use synchronized keyword while using DateFormat in a multithreading environment?

I am getting below `Exception`:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

When I looked into my code, I have a method that formats the Date using `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
public static synchronized String now(String dateFormat) {

            if (dateFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
            }
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = null;
            if (dateFormat == null || dateFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
            } else {
                sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault());
            }
            return sdf.format(cal.getTime());

        }
```

Although I could not reproduce the exception, this probably a place where I may encountered the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because I found a [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/java-best-practices-dateformat-in.html) that describes that how to use `DateFormat` in a multithreading environment. `DateFormat` are not synchronized so while working in multithreading environment it may throw the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

But my above method is already a `synchronized` method.

My question is:

Is static method can be a `synchronized` method?

Do I need to synchronize the object of `SimpleDateFormat` instead of `synchronized` method and why?

Comment: you could have a look at this http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/java-best-practices-dateformat-in.html

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` in your case is a local variable so it is thread safe because it is "thread local". By the way, that method does not need to be `synchronized` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method shown above does not access any shared state (the DateFormat is created as a local variable), so you do not need to synchronize it *at all*.

You need to find the stacktrace associated with your exception. Otherwise it is just guess-work.